# Defining a type using a recursive Type -> Type function

Tags: idris

In Idris, normally `List` is defined like so:

```
data List a = Nil | (::) a (List a)
```

But I wanted to try defining `List` without `data`, using a recursive `Type -> Type` function:

```
List' : Type -> Type
List' a = Either () (a, List' a)
```

This compiles, but I cannot match on the `Either` cases. For example, if I define

```
isEmpty : List' a -> Bool
isEmpty (Left _) = True
isEmpty (Right _) = False
```

the compiler says:

```
When checking left hand side of isEmpty:
When checking an application of Main.isEmpty:
        Type mismatch between
                Either a1 b (Type of Left l)
        and
                List' a (Expected type)
```

So the typechecker doesn't seem to expand `List' a` into its `Either _ _` definition. It seems that the recursive call in the type definition trips up the typechecker -- if I instead define `List'` like so:

```
List' a = Either () (a, ())
```

then the `isEmpty` definition compiles fine. (But of course it's not actually a list anymore.)

What I'd like to know is:

- Why exactly does this not work? Is there a way to inspect what is going on inside the typechecker?
- Is there a way to make this kind of type definition work? Or do we *have* to use [`data`](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/reference/syntax-guide.html#data-types)?

Comment: Only total definitions are expanded during typechecking. If you try marking `List'` as `%total`, it will be rejected.